# Tic-Tac-Toe Game In Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a tic-tac-toe game on java.

This is the code I've got so far (that works) and I don't really understand how to draw circles instead of cross:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare variables
    int[][] board = new int[3][3];
    int turns = 0, x, y, mode, score = 0;
    String dec;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Constants
    final int EMPTY = 0;
    final int FILL_O = 1;
    final int FILL_X = 2;

    //Ask user for game type
    System.out.println("TicTacToe\n=========");
    System.out.print("(1) or (2) players? ");
    mode = s.nextInt();

    //Draw the board
    StdDraw.setScale(0, 3);
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.008);
    for (int c = 0; c <= 3; c++) {
        StdDraw.line(c, 0, c, 3);
    }
    for (int c = 0; c <= 3; c++) {
        StdDraw.line(0, c, 3, c);
    }

    //Two-player Game
    if (mode == 2) {
        //X goes first
        StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.BLUE);
        while (turns < 9) {
            //Draw Os on odd turns
            if (turns % 2 == 1) {
                if (StdDraw.mousePressed()) {
                    x = (int) Math.floor(StdDraw.mouseX());
                    y = (int) Math.floor(StdDraw.mouseY());
                    if (board[x][y] == EMPTY) {
                        StdDraw.circle(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, 0.5);
                        board[x][y] = FILL_O;
                        mode = FILL_O; //Since mode is no longer in use, I 
    reinstate it to track turns
                        StdDraw.show(500);
                        turns++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Depends on what that API provides in `edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw` .. but if this is just a util library for Graphics, yes it is possible.

Comment: do you know how I can implement it to my current code?

Comment: Instead of using `StdDraw.text(x, y, board[x][y] + "");` test the value of `board[x][y]` and call a function that draws either a square or a circle at coordinates x or y.

Comment: Use `filledCircle` and `filledRectangle`

Comment: Don't edit the question with a completly new question. Create a new post if you need. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (that link is valid for every question you post ;) )

Comment: In your edit, you should keep the `StdDraw` tag and import statement. You are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `StdDraw.text(x, y, board[x][y] + "");` test the value of `board[x][y]` and call a function that draws either a square or a circle at coordinates x or y.

To illustrate that, replace

```
for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < board[x].length; y++) {
        StdDraw.text(x, y, board[x][y] + "");
    }
}
```

with

```
for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < board[x].length; y++) {
        if (board[x][y] == 'X') {
            StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, 0.5 );
        }
        else if (board[x][y] == 'O') {
            StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, 0.5 );
        }
    }
}
```

Make some tests to find a nice value for the radius, 0.5 will probably not be good.

Answer (score 0):

That API provided the methods `filledCircle` and `filledRectangle`.

```
public static void  filledCircle(double x, double y, double r) ;
```

> Draw filled circle of radius r, centered on (x, y).
>
> Parameters:
>      - x the x-coordinate of the center of the circle
>      - y the y-coordinate of the center of the circle
>      - r the radius of the circle

```
public static void  filledRectangle(double x, double y, double halfWidth, double halfHeight);
```

> Draw a filled rectangle of given half width and half height, centered on (x, y).
>
> Parameters:
>      - x the x-coordinate of the center of the rectangle
>      - y the y-coordinate of the center of the rectangle
>      - halfWidth is half the width of the rectangle
>      - halfHeight is half the height of the rectangle

Or see `filledSquare`... basicly the same idea of rectamgle but with the same value in parameter..

Something like

```
//CENTER
int x = (int) Math.floor(StdDraw.mouseX());
int y = (int) Math.floor(StdDraw.mouseY());
int r = 10; //radius
StdDraw.filledcircle(x, y, r);
```

And

```
//CENTER
int x = (int) Math.floor(StdDraw.mouseX());
int y = (int) Math.floor(StdDraw.mouseY());
int width = 10; 
int height = 10; 
//The method use the center of the shape and half of both "length"
StdDraw.filledRectangle(x, y, height  / 2, height / 2);
```